# Toggling between Hangul and Latin alphabets in Korean IME (Win 8)

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, input-languages, korean

Picking up from [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/479338/hotkey-to-switch-between-hangul-and-latin-input-input-modes-with-windows-7-korea) as none of the solutions listed there seem to be coming through for me. Any help greatly appreciated!

Working in Windows 8 64-bit with three 'language/layout pairs' installed: English with AZERTY layout, English with QWERTY layout, Korean with AZERTY layout.

As with the previous poster, I can use hotkeys to toggle between my different language/layout pairs, but have no hotkey to switch from hangul to latin within the Korean IME. At the moment I'm using the mouse to press the button on the language bar, which is slow and annoying.

Things I've tried:

- **<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>:** toggles through all 3 pairs, but won't toggle within the Korean IME
- **<kbd>Any Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Any Shift</kbd>:** toggles from English/QWERTY to English/AZERTY only
- **<kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Any Shift</kbd>:** toggles from English/AZERTY to Korean/AZERTY only
- **<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>:** Does nothing, whether pressed on its own or with either of the Shifts
- **<kbd>한/영</kbd> key on the on-screen Korean IME keyboard:** does nothing
- Also used "Change Key Sequence" to set shortcut for Korean, but again all this does is bring up the Korean/AZERTY pair; it doesn't allow to toggle between hangul and latin within the IME

I'm at a bit of a loss at this stage - does anyone have any other recommendations?